# JBoss EAP 7.1.6, CDI 1.2 and exclude scan don't work

Tags: java, jboss, cdi

I'm using JBoss EAP 7.1.6 (with weld-api-2.4.0.SP1-redhat-1.jar). My web application (war) embeds a "common" library which contains an alternative bean, like this:

```
@Alternative
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProvider {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

My web application doesn't use this alternative bean. In this case, I don't have any persistence mechanism.
When I deploy the webapp (with a dependency to the third-party library), I receive the following stacktrace:

```
15:01:08,196 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sample-monitoring.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sample-monitoring.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named «  » in deployment sample-monitoring.war  for injection point private javax.persistence.EntityManager org.sample.EntityManagerProvider.entityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.getScopedPUName(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.registerPersistenceContextInjectionPoint(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:77)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:350)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:338)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createFieldResourceInjection(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:216)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.discoverType(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:448)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.getResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.<init>(ResourceInjector.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.of(ResourceInjector.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.<init>(BeanInjectionTarget.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.createDefault(BeanInjectionTarget.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:80)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

I try to explicit exclude the scan of the the persistence class in the beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="all" version="1.2">
        <scan>
            <exclude name="com.other.library.dao.util.EntityManagerProvider" />
            <exclude name="com.other.library.dao.util.**" />
        </scan>
</beans>
```

But I still receive the same error :-(

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the exact code of the `EntityManagerProvider`? I find it strange that a library declares an alternative this way. Is there a `beans.xml` file in the JAR of the library? What are its contents? By the way, the `<scan><exclude>` works for the same bean archive, so you will not be able to exclude a bean from the library this way!

Comment: Yes, there is a beans.xml in third party library :

    <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
 bean-discovery-mode="annotated" version="1.2">

    </beans>

Comment: @RigobertSong did you find a solution for this? I'm trying to exclude a bean from a project dependency, without success.